# Imputation diagnostics in MICE for factors

Tags: r, r-mice

I imputed my data using both the packages `mice` and `miceRanger` and I would like to compare the distributions of the imputed variables with the original data. In `miceRanger` this is very easy using the function `plotDistributions()` which displays density plots for the numeric variables and barplots for factors.
In `mice`, **if the variables are numeric**, it is easy to compare the distributions using `stripplot()` or `bwplot()`, but I cannot find a simple way to do it **if the variables are factors**. I wonder if I am missing something or I just have to give in and create a custom routine for that.

Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted `PlotDistributions()` from `miceRanger` to work with `mice`.

Beware this function has been only tested quickly on 2 random datasets, therefore I cannot guarantee it does not contain bugs.

For more info, see [here](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/525)

```
PlotDist <- function (miceObj, vars = names(miceObj$imp), dotsize = 0.5, 
                    ...) 
{
  pos <- which(miceObj$nmis!=0)
  vars <- vars[pos]
  newClasses <- sapply(miceObj$data[pos], class)
  if (vars[[1]] == "allCategorical") 
    vars <- names(newClasses[newClasses == "factor"])
  if (vars[[1]] == "allNumeric") 
    vars <- names(newClasses[newClasses != "factor"])
  newClasses <- newClasses[vars]
  facVars <- newClasses[newClasses == "factor"]
  numVars <- newClasses[newClasses != "factor"]
  if (length(facVars) > 0) {
    facList <- lapply(names(facVars), function(var) {
      dat <- as.data.table(miceObj$imp[[var]])
      dat <- melt(dat, measure.vars = names(dat))
      setnames(dat, "value", var)
      agg <- dat[, .(Percentage = .N/sum(miceObj$where[, var])), by = c("variable", var)]
      rawAgg <- na.omit(as.data.table(mice$data),cols = var)[, .(Percentage = .N/sum(!miceObj$where[,  var])), by = var]
      return(ggplot() + geom_dotplot(data = agg, aes(x = !!sym(var), 
                                                     y = !!sym("Percentage")), 
                                     binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", 
                                     dotsize = dotsize, stackratio = 0.75, binwidth = 1/50) + 
               geom_bar(data = rawAgg, aes(x = !!sym(var), y = !!sym("Percentage")), 
                        stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) + 
               scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)))
    })
  }
  else facList <- NULL
  if (length(numVars) > 0) {
    numList <- lapply(names(numVars), function(var) {
      dat <- as.data.table(miceObj$imp[[var]])
      dat <- melt(dat, measure.vars = names(dat))
      setnames(dat, "value", var)
      dens <- density(miceObj$data[, get(var)], na.rm = TRUE)
      return(ggplot() + geom_density(data = dat, aes(!!sym(var), group = !!sym("variable")), bw = dens$bw) + 
               geom_density(data = miceObj$data[!is.na(get(var))], aes(!!sym(var)), 
                            linewidth = 1, color = "red", bw = dens$bw) + 
               ylab("Density"))
    })
  }
  else numList <- NULL
  pList <- c(numList, facList)
  ggarrange(plotlist = pList, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there isn't a `mice`-equivalent function similar to `miceRanger::plotDistributions()` (which is disappointing because it's a very convenient function). However, you can use [`ggmice`](https://amices.org/ggmice/articles/ggmice.html) to use `ggplot2` syntax on `mids` objects.

```
library(miceRanger)
library(mice)
library(ggmice)
data(nhanes)
nhanes$hyp <- factor(nhanes$hyp)

## miceRanger
imp1 <- miceRanger(data = nhanes)
plotDistributions(imp1)
```

[image]

```
## mice and ggmice
imp2 <- mice(data = nhanes)
ggmice(imp2, aes(x = hyp)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! After your comment I had a look into the miceRanger function, which is not too complicated and I adapted it for mice. I also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/525) and let's see what the package owner says. Maybe it will be included in the package, being it such a handy function.